# How to avoid StaticText overlap or move away from each other in wxPython when some text length changes later during code execution?

Tags: wxpython

I have some StaticText that may change its content during code execution. The text is used as title and has two parts – a description and a related data (still as another text), each part with different text color.

The problem is that the texts maintain their position as it happened to be when the program was first launched, so any later text change will result either in text parts overlap or move away from each other, at random.

What I need is some refresh (or reset) so that the program forgets everything about where it displayed the texts last time and then displays the texts as if started the program for the first time. How can I do that ?

Here is a test code; for simplicity, the relevance related to question applies only at first click:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.SetSize((400, 300))
        self.SetTitle("test frame")
        self.panel_1 = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_1.Add(sizer_2, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)

        self.variable_length_label = wx.StaticText(self.panel_1, wx.ID_ANY, "label: ")
        self.variable_length_label.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(0x00, 0x66, 0x66))
        sizer_2.Add(self.variable_length_label, 0, 0, 0)

        self.actual_data = wx.StaticText(self.panel_1, wx.ID_ANY, "ABC")
        self.actual_data.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(0xff, 0x66, 0x00))
        sizer_2.Add(self.actual_data, 0, 0, 0)

        self.button = wx.Button(self.panel_1, wx.ID_ANY, "Click once for longer text label and new data")
        self.button.SetToolTip("This example has relevance only on first click")
        sizer_1.Add(self.button, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.panel_1.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        self.Layout()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_click, self.button)

    def on_click(self, event):
        self.variable_length_label.SetLabel("muchlongertextlabel: ")
        self.actual_data.SetLabel("DEF")

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform a `Layout()` to ask the sizers to rearrange themselves around the new child data.
You have applied the sizers to `panel_1` so you should ask for that to be laid out anew.
In this case, the following will toggle the text between long and short versions.

```
def on_click(self, event):
    t = self.actual_data.GetLabel()
    if t == "ABC":
        self.variable_length_label.SetLabel("muchlongertextlabel: ")
        self.actual_data.SetLabel("DEF")
    else:
        self.variable_length_label.SetLabel("label: ")
        self.actual_data.SetLabel("ABC")
    self.panel_1.Layout()
```